# How to implement an asynchronous function with Rest Api Bundle in Symfony 3.2

Tags: multithreading, symfony, events, process

I'm still looking for a solution to implement an asynchronous call before returning a response. In other words, I have a **long asynchronous process** which should start running before returning a response, a user should not be waiting a long time for the end of this process:

```
$data = ....

...//Here call to an asynchronous function <<----

return $this->getSuccessResponse($data);
```

I tried with Events, Thread, Process, but no result.
What should I do ? (something expect RabbitMQ)

Comment: @Robert Wade, thank you for your grammar's corrections.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a queuing system like Beanstalk. With this bundle [LeezyPheanstalkBundle](https://github.com/armetiz/LeezyPheanstalkBundle) you can manage the queues.

In the controller, insert the job in the queue. And, in a command running with supervisor, execute your task.

**Edit:**

You can use an [EventSubscriber](https://github.com/armetiz/LeezyPheanstalkBundle/blob/master/src/Resources/doc/4-events.md)

Comment: It looks interesting, by the way, I tried with events, but Symfony official documentation make me sick sometimes, it's not clear and they made it more difficult to understand.